# Can't access the Status Report page

Tags: 8, updating, debugging

I've updated my LOCAL site with composer, updated the database but can't access the Status Report page (site encountered an unexpected error). I looked at the recent log messages and saw this error:

> Location  http://i.l/admin/reports/status
>
> Message   Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The
>   "phpmailer" plugin does not exist. in
>   Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of
>   /home/www/mySite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Worth a try: Download https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/archive/v6.0.5.zip, extract and rename folder to `phpmailer`, in your Drupal's webroot create directory `libraries` and move the `phpmailer` library into it.

Comment: No, didn't fix it. This problem with Status Report page appeared only on my local computer. I guess this is due to some plugin or something missing in my local environment.